Prisma "circular variable reference" bug
I'm currently using Prisma with Next.js app router/API routes and Postgres to manage our backend. I've been running into some strange problems - every time I try to call an API route, I get a massive spam of code in the terminal followed by the following error:
What I've done to resolve:

Looked over schema for circular references
Migrated BE to entirely new next.js project
Tried new schema
Tried running extremely simple BE route that sends a POST request and updates DB
Removing unnecessary modules from package.json

Perhaps this is an error with the way the backend is setup or something external to Prisma like a flaw in code? I'm quite stumped with this and haven't found anything via Googling, would appreciate some assistance here!
Schema (not including generator or datasource):
enum Role {
  SUPER_ADMIN
  ADMIN
  USER
}

enum IntegrationName {
  SLACK
  EMAIL
}

model User {
  id        String     @id @default(uuid())
  authId    String?    @unique
  name      String
  email     String     @unique
  createdAt DateTime   @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamp(0)
  updatedAt DateTime   @default(now()) @updatedAt @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamp(0)
  chats     Chat[]
  teamUser  TeamUser[]
}

model TeamUser {
  teamId Int
  userId String
  role   Role   @default(USER)
  team   Team   @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id])
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  @@id([teamId, userId])
}

model Team {
  id           Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String
  slug         String        @unique
  members      TeamUser[]
  integrations Integration[] @relation("TeamIntegrations")
  createdAt    DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime      @updatedAt
}

model Chat {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  isPublic Boolean
  messages Message[]
  metaData Json
  user     User?     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId   String?
}

model Message {
  id           Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  chatId       Int
  chat         Chat    @relation(fields: [chatId], references: [id])
  fromComputer Boolean
  content      String
}

model Integration {
  id    Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  IntegrationName
  teams Team[]          @relation("TeamIntegrations")
}

Example output below:
- *0* ???*1*["cwd"]
  ⚠️  unknown object
- *1* arguments[0]
  ⚠️  function calls are not analysed yet
- *2* {"cwd": ???*3*, "path": process.env*5*[???*6*()], "execPath": ???*7*, ...???*9*}["cwd"]
  ⚠️  spread object
  ⚠️  This value might have side effects
- *3* process.cwd*4*()
  ⚠️  process.cwd is not specified in the environment
  ⚠️  This value might have side effects
- *4* process.cwd: The Node.js process.cwd method: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processcwd
- *5* process.env: The Node.js process.env property: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processenv
- *6* A["exports"]
  ⚠️  sequence with side effects
  ⚠️  This value might have side effects
- *7* process*8*["execPath"]
  ⚠️  unsupported property on Node.js process object
  ⚠️  This value might have side effects
- *8* process: The Node.js process module: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html
- *9* e
  ⚠️  circular variable reference
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/nutuKwqP.png

